# EPiServer and Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)

Tags: episerver, wif, episerver-6

I am researching the possibilities of using WIF to identify users on *parts* of a customer's site running on EPiServer. I've managed to get WIF to kick in using, amongst others, the following post:

http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Ben-Morris/Dates/2010/6/Converting-EPiServer-6-to-use-claims-based-authentication-with-WIF/

This works nicely if you set

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

in web.config, making all requests require an authenticated user. However, we would like to use EPiServer to separate what content should be available to anonymous users and authenticated users. The problem is, I just can't get it to work.

When I enable WIF, and don't set `deny users="*"`, EPiServer kicks in and outputs some text to the response stream before WIF is enable to perform the redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 01 Nov 2011 07:51:04 GMT
Connection: close

Access denied.

</pre></table></table></table></table></table></font></font></font></font></font></i></i></i></i></i></b></b></b></b></b></u></u></u></u></u><p>&nbsp;</p><hr>
```

This results in the following error when WIF tries to redirect to the STS:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot redirect after
>   HTTP headers have been sent.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have
>   been sent.]    System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean
>   endResponse) +8712587
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectToIdentityProvider(String
>   uniqueId, String returnUrl, Boolean persist) +249
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnEndRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs args) +438
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

I have searched both high and low to be able to override this behavior. In EPiServer.dll, I found the following place which outputs text similar to what is output:

`AccessDeniedDelegateHandler.cs`, method `BrowserLogonAccessDenied(object sender)`:

```
internal static void BrowserLogonAccessDenied(object sender)
{
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "401 Unauthorized";
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Access denied.");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

This code is called from the following two places, as far as I can see:

- `EPiServer.Global`, method `protected virtual void HandleAccessDenied()`
- `EPiServer.PageBase`, method `public virtual void AccessDenied()`

I have tried to override `HandleAccessDenied` in `Global.asax`, and override `AccessDenied` in my page template. However, the "Access denied" text is still output. It looks as if the override of `AcccessDenied` in my page template is firing, however, the override of `HandleAccessDenied` does not seem to fire.

Any hints on what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I tried overriding the `AccessDenied` method of `PageBase`, however, I did the same "mistake" as the default implementation, namely to flush the response stream:

```
    public override void AccessDenied()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        Response.Flush(); // <- This was the problem
        Response.End();
        // The rest is handled by WIF when we send a HTTP 401, think nothing more of it..
    }
```

The solution was to simply avoid flushing the response stream. Then WIF handles the rest:

```
    public override void AccessDenied()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        // Removed the flushing of the response
        Response.End();
        // The rest is handled by WIF when we send a HTTP 401, think nothing more of it..
    }
```

This allows us to use the authorization of EPI to control which users had access to each page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding the AccessDenied behaviour, you can add a special login form (since you are still relying on forms authentication) to actually trigger the login.

```
public class FederatedLoginHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(context.User.Identity.Name, false);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
    }
}
```

Setup the handler in web.config with

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <!--"Fake" login handler, simply triggers WIF auth-->
    <add name="LoginForm" path="federatedlogin.ashx" verb="GET,HEAD" type="SomeAssembly.FederatedLoginHandler" />
    ...
```

And finally setup authentication to use the new handler

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".LoginPage" loginUrl="federatedlogin.ashx" timeout="120" />
</authentication>
```

This strategy does not require modifying EPiServer, WIF or standard ASP.Net behaviour. Of course, you need the basic WIF configuration to get this to work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638734.aspx.

Comment: I'm not relying on Forms authentication, but maybe that would be a good idea. But, the only reason I have to override the EPiServer functionality, is because they flush the response streams if you're not using forms auth. I think the correct fix would be for EPiServer built-in functionality to not flush the response stream. Then WIF would work out-of-the-box...